# How to convert string containg comma into array in ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-1.9.2

I have a string like below

```
 "\"123\",\"Columbia, Gem Of The Ocean\""
```

I want to convert it into array and I should get an output like below

```
["123","Columbia, Gem Of The Ocean"]
```

But when i use split by comma method on string i get an output like below

```
 ["\"123\"", "\"Columbia", " Gem Of The Ocean\""]
```

It is splitting "Columbia, Gem Of The Ocean" by `","` but i don't want that.

There is a `parse_line method of csv` but that doesn't work in `ruby 1.9.2.`

Please suggest some solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description and the expected result do not match. You don't want to split it by (all) commas. You want to extract the parts surrounded by double quotation.

```
string.scan(/".*?"/)
```

If you don't want the quotations, then

```
string.scan(/"(.*?)"/).flatten(1)
```